# Deploying Cloudflare page function with external dependency fails: `Could not resolve [package]`

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I am deploying a CF page function with an external dependecy

I installed it locally with `npm install jspdf` and then my pages works locally. It also generated package.json and package-lock.json. I commited and pushed to my repo, but then my build fails with the following logs:

```
3:08:10.954    Cloning repository...
23:08:12.065    From https://github.com/charelF/wg-form-page
23:08:12.065     * branch            bf14b72070afb75b1b8c4a5e13d5caa3b7aea792 -> FETCH_HEAD
23:08:12.066    
23:08:12.110    HEAD is now at bf14b72 nice
23:08:12.111    
23:08:12.219    
23:08:12.252    Success: Finished cloning repository files
23:08:12.979    No build command specified. Skipping build step.
23:08:12.980    Found Functions directory at /functions. Uploading.
23:08:14.565    ✘ [ERROR] 1 error(s) and 0 warning(s) when compiling Worker.
23:08:14.566    
23:08:14.566    
23:08:14.569    
23:08:14.570    ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "jspdf"
23:08:14.571    
23:08:14.571        pdfmaker.js:1:22:
23:08:14.571          1 │ import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'
23:08:14.571            ╵                       ~~~~~~~
23:08:14.571    
23:08:14.571      You can mark the path "jspdf" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
23:08:14.572    
23:08:14.572    
23:08:14.575    ✘ [ERROR] Build failed with 1 error:
23:08:14.575    
23:08:14.575      pdfmaker.js:1:22: ERROR: Could not resolve "jspdf"
23:08:14.575    
23:08:14.575    
23:08:14.585    Failed building Pages Functions.
23:08:15.476    Failed: an internal error occurred. If this continues, contact support: https://cfl.re/3WgEyrH
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i used no framework, I left the build command empty. However then nothing gets build, which is why the above logs show the error. The solution is to include anything in the build command. In my case, I put: `echo "Hello World!"` in the buidl command and then the deployment worked.

Originally asked on discord: https://discord.com/channels/595317990191398933/910978223968518144/1155069343365865534

A github issue was opened because of this issue: https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-docs/issues/10841

Answer (score 0):

You can put `npm/yarn/pnpm install` for **Build command** (under Settings > Build & deployments > Build configurations).

I also enabled **Build cache**, tho I can't verify if the build process is faster or not since currently I only have 3 dependencies (1 dependencies, 2 devDependencies)

HTH